# Is there a way to disable mouse action on codemirror?

Tags: codemirror

How can I disable mouse usage in codemirror.

I want it to behave like vim editor where the user cannot move anywhere using the mouse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `pointer-events: none;` on the editor container?

```css
.CodeMirror {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[<kbd><sub>[image: jsfiddle-icon]</sub> **Demo!**</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVpFA.png)

#### See also

- [`pointer-events` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on *MDN*
- The [feature's compatibility matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) on *caniuse.com*

Answer (score 2):

You can register handlers for the mouse events (mostly `mousedown`), and simply `.preventDefault()` them to prevent CodeMirror from handling them further.

Comment: you should really trust this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After long search, I was able to disable mouse actions in code mirror editor by preventing the default behavior of the `onMouseDownCapture` event. handler.

```
  onMouseDownCapture={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
```

```js
    <CodeMirror
      ref={(editor) => editorRefCallback(editor, highlightedRange)}
      extensions={[
        EditorView.editable.of(false),
        getLanguageHighlighter(language),
      ]}
      maxHeight={height}
      value={code}
      editable={false}
      onMouseDownCapture={(e) => e.preventDefault()} // prevent default behavior of code mirror
      autoFocus={true}
      basicSetup={{ highlightActiveLine: true }}
      theme={currentTheme}
    />
```